# Not able to place the order using paypal in magento 2 rest

Tags: magento2, php, paypal, rest-api

I am developing an e-commerce mobile application using **Magento 2 rest** APIs only. This is the flow for making the REST API calls for order placement.

**`1.Create a cart`**

api -->`{{url}}/index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine`

This API will return a unique **cart id**

**`2.Add products to cart`**

api --> `{{url}}/index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine/items`

body ->

```
{
 "cart_item": {
     "quote_id": cartId,
     "sku": skuName,
     "qty": 1
     }
}
```

**`3. Estimate Shipping Methods`**

url --> `{{url}}/index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods`

body ->

```
{
    "address": {
        "region": "Trivandrum",
        "region_id": 12,
        "region_code": "CA",
        "country_id": "IN",
        "street": [
            "Amstor house",
            "Eramam"
        ],
        "telephone": "5656565454",
        "postcode": "670390",
        "city": "Kazhakuttam",
        "firstname": "Peter",
        "lastname": "K",
        "same_as_billing": 0,
        "save_in_address_book": 0
    }

}
```

This will return all possible shipping methods based on shipping address. In my case the result is

```
[
  {
    "carrier_code": "freeshipping",
    "method_code": "freeshipping",
    "carrier_title": "Free Shipping",
    "method_title": "Free",
    "amount": 0,
    "base_amount": 0,
    "available": true,
    "error_message": "",
    "price_excl_tax": 0,
    "price_incl_tax": 0
  }
]
```

**`4)Save shipping information`**

url --> `{{url}}/index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine/shipping-information`

body data ->

```
{
    "addressInformation": {
        "shipping_address": {

            "region": "Trivandrum",
            "region_id": 12,
            "region_code": "CA",
            "country_id": "IN",
            "street": [
                "Amstor house",
                "Eramam"
            ],
            "telephone": "5656565454",
            "postcode": "670390",
            "city": "Kazhakuttam",
            "firstname": "Peter",
            "lastname": "K",

        },
        "billing_address": {
            "region": "Trivandrum",
            "region_id": 12,
            "region_code": "CA",
            "country_id": "IN",
            "street": [
                "Amstor house",
                "Eramam"
            ],
            "telephone": "5656565454",
            "postcode": "670390",
            "city": "Kazhakuttam",
            "firstname": "Peter",
            "lastname": "K",
        },
        "shipping_method_code": "freeshipping",
        "shipping_carrier_code": "freeshipping"


    }
}
```

This will return all possible payment methods. Here I am using `paypal_express` for payment.

**`5. Payment using PayPal plugin`**

Here i will pay the amount using  [paypal cordova plugin](http://paypal%20cordova%20plugin).Also configured the IPN [{{url}}/paypal/ipn/]in paypal account

This API will return the following data,

```
{
   "client": {
       "environment": "sandbox",
       "paypal_sdk_version": "2.14.4",
       "platform": "Android",
       "product_name": "PayPal-Android-SDK"
   },
   "response": {
       "create_time": "2016-11-19T05:25:46Z",
       "id": "PAY-5VS11410F5341972MLAX6ETA",
       "intent": "sale",
       "state": "approved"
   },
   "response_type": "payment"
}
```

**`5.Save payment and place order`**

url --> `{{url}}/index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine/payment-information`

data ->

```
{
    "cartId": 3,
    "billingAddress‌": {
        "region": "Trivandrum",
        "region_id": 12,
        "region_code": "CA",
        "country_id": "IN",
        "street": [
            "Amstor house",
            "Eramam"
        ],
        "telephone": "5656565454",
        "postcode": "670390",
        "city": "Kazhakuttam",
        "firstname": "Peter",
        "lastname": "K"
    },
    "paymentMethod": {
        "method": "paypal_express"

    }
}
```

But this api will returning

```
{
  "message": "PayPal gateway has rejected the request. Invalid token (#10410: Invalid token)."
}
```

Is there any api missing in the above flow for capturing payments.P lease help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass PayPal transaction data to Manento REST.

For more info see [Magento 2 REST API PayPal Payment method](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135816/magento-2-rest-api-paypal-payment-method)

```
{
    "paymentMethod": {
        "method": "paypal_express",
        "additional_data": {
            "paypal_express_checkout_token" : "EC-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "paypal_express_checkout_redirect_required" : false,
            "paypal_express_checkout_payer_id" : "XXXXXXXXXX"
        }
    }
}
```