# Order is not create Magento 2 Rest API

Tags: magento2, payment, paypal-payflow-pro

I am Testing Order Place API with Swagger.

Its successfully Working fine with Purchase Order and Check money.

now, I am checking with Payflow Pro than its giving an error.

*message: "Invalid account number"*

here is my request which I have passed in swagger

```
{
  "email":"ketan@yahoo.com",
   "paymentMethod":{
   "po_number":"string",
  "method":"payflowpro",
  "additional_data":{
        "user" : "****",
        "vendor" : "****",
        "partner" : "paypal",
        "pwd" : "****",
        "verbosity" : "HIGH",
        "BUTTONSOURCE" : "Magento_Cart_Community",
        "tender" : "C",
        "trxtype" : "A",
        "createsecuretoken" : "Y",
        "CUSTIP":"Local IP",
        "securetokenid" : "4a2dd2d5f4cabb9fdd8a590f2ce0bc5a",
        "silenttran" : "TRUE",
        "firstname" : "fname",
        "lastname" : "lname",
        "street" : "address",
        "city" : "Greer",
        "state" : "SC",
        "zip" : "29650",
        "country" : "US",
        "shiptofirstname" : "sname",
        "shiptolastname" : "slname",
        "shiptostreet" : "address",
        "shiptocity" : "Greer",
        "shiptostate" : "SC",
        "shiptozip" : "29650",
        "shiptocountry" : "US"
  },
  "extension_attributes":{
     "agreement_ids":[
        "string"
        ]
      }
   }
}
```

and here is the response

```
'result' => 
   array (
    'result' => '23',
    'pnref' => 'A1X0AC170F0A',
   'respmsg' => 'Invalid account number',
   'result_code' => '23',
  )
```

If anyone knows which parameter we have to pass for a guest please let us know?

Comment: Anyone find any solution for API for Payflow pro????